# RCurl cannot delete file via ftp

Tags: r, ftp, delete-file, rcurl

I am using RCurl and am having big trouble trying to delete a file (filename.txt) on an ftp account (`username:password`) on the ftp server `ftp://ftp.foo.bar`.

I simply cannot make it work, for example I tried:

```
httpDELETE("ftp://ftp.foo.bar/filename.txt", userpwd = "username:password")
```

and

```
curlPerform(url = "ftp ://ftp.foo.bar/filename.txt", customrequest = "DELETE", userpwd =  "username:password")
```

They both return (OK 0) but the file is still there.

I tried some variations of the url to no avail.

Can you guys point me in the right direction?

Many thanks.
Erw.

Comment: Hello, I would suggest to include some of your code. Thanks!

Comment: Dear Fabrizio, thanks for ypur input. Actually this code above (example a and b) is what I used and it did not work when I execute it. I only need to delete the file. It is the lines I showed above that do not work. If you can show me how to delete a file via ftp (wth user/pass) then I would be much endebted. Thanks a ton. Erw.

Comment: I have spent 12 hours on this and found a very surprising work-around:

ftpUpload(what="readme.txt", to=x, userpwd=upw, postquote = c("DELE somefile"))

Due to the postquote this will actually remove somefile from the ftp account. I am quite surprised that this works; nothing with DELETE, DELE, -DELETE, -DELE, RM or -RM in the customrequest option with curlPerform works at all. It could be a bug, but more likely me not fully understanding how to approach it with curlPerform.

Comment: I am sorry that you could not find anybody to help you. My advice is to make very well written question and if you actively participate in the website your probabilities of getting an answer should increase